# Why is RAM-usage of empty libGDX-App climbing steadily?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, libgdx, garbage-collection

gurus out there,

I'm relativly new to libGDX (and Java-Programming in general) and have a question regarding the RAM-usage of libGDX applications, that I couldn't find the answer for online.
I few days ago when I was customizing a game-example from the book "Java Game Development with LibGDX" that I currently read, I noticed that the RAM-usage of that game spiked when left alone for about an 1h. My Linux resource-monitor started with ~120MB and got up to 1300MB by the time I closed it down. I already contacted the author on this matter, since I went by his book, line by line and still got this behavior!

Apart from the probable leaks in his examples I decided to dig deeper and created an empty LibGDX-App using the most recent gdx-setup.jar (v. 1.9.9) and decided to let it run for a while.
I tested this on my workstation using a Ryzen 2700X, 32GB RAM and Linux Mint 19.1.
Interestingly the empty app showed a similiar yet not so drastic behavior with RAM-usage continuing to climb over time from ~50MB to ~260MB by the time I shut down, without even one single drop back down!
I read online that resource-monitors actually don't display what the running game inside the java-process consumes, but mix in some JVM-stuff. So I decided to analyze further with the help of jConsole and VisualVW. I was suspecting a lazy GC, but both tools showed that GC ran periodically. Still, my OS's resource monitor showed this continuously climbing RAM-usage in the empty LibGdx-App, though it was doing nothing but staring me in the face with it's annoying Bad Logic-Smiley on red background ;-).

I already did an intensive search on the forum and stackoverflow on the topic of memory-leaks and RAM-consupmtion of LibGDX, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. So I wonder if this behavior is something to worry about or if this is normal? If so, and even empty app have a continous climb in RAM-usage, how could one ever detect if everything is fine or if the app leaks memory?
I would highly appreciate if some of you LibGDX-gurus could share your wisdom on this topic with a noob like me :-)

Thx in advance
- codeArist

Comment: Lets see what this empty libgdx app looks like

Comment: It's just the default app that's created when using the gdx-setup.jar. No additions, no edit...

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on memory management topics and not a wise guru, but I have just a simple libGDX game out there. 
I developed it with the following strategy that I am running since I began to implement my first program more than 25 years ago: Always test on low end hardware. If everythings run smoothly, then everything's fine. My libGDX game runs fine on low end Android devices from 2011 on, the iOS version performs well on iPhones from 2013. On today's mid range mobile devices, Android version is nearly never killed to save memory. Although I play my game around 10 times a day and it goes to foreground for this, the process is apparently not memory hungry enough for Android to decide it getting closed. Reviewers on the Play Store praise the game for running smooth on low end devices.

So my answer for you is: There's no problem with libGDX, perhaps you just watch some JVM behaviour on your system. Write your game, test it on a low end device - use an old Galaxy S3 or a Moto G, or if you plan just to release for Desktop use your old 2011 business laptop to test. If everything's working well, don't try to track down or fix a nonexistant problem.

And by the way, you are welcome to join the libGDX discord that is linked on the Github page. That's the right place for such discussions and we have some guys hanging out there that really examined memory behaviour before.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. That does sound pretty reasonable. Although, I have to admit that I find it a bit frustrating to not understand why the the JVM process for an empty LibGDX project continues to hog so much memory. Especially since period Full GCs do happen according to VisualVM!
Anyway, thanks for the tipp with Discord. I will definitely try my luck there :-)